# Button for cross posts to/from Math SE

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, math-stackexchange, cross-posting

People explained me that it is possible to ask same questions in Math SE and MO, and I did this from time to time. I think it's very important to have this possibility, because often you haven't enough experience to estimate if your question is simple, or not. That is why when I am not sure that the question is of research level, I prefer to post it first at Math SE, and only if there is no answer, I ask it in MO.

But yesterday my cross post lead to a situation when [people duplicated their efforts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715947/a-linear-functional-on-ck-continuous-on-each-l-1-mu). That was my fault, of course, since I forgot to give a reference in the original post (it was late night in my city, I am sorry).

I want to avoid this situation in future for newcomers. My question is

> if it is possible to make a special button "cross post" so that when people push it, the necessary links (between two posts) appear automatically, together with [the explanation of when it is proper to use this opportunity](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se)?

This could be organized like the procedure of bounty now: after two days it becomes possible to cross post the question. What do you think?

Comment: I think simultaneous cross-posts should rather be avoided than supported and encouraged. That said, if you have posted a question to Math.SE, and there is no answer for a considerable time and for a couple of consecutive days almost nobody looks at your question (check the view count), then you can delete the question on Math.SE and post it on MO, with a notice that it has previously been asked on Math.SE without success.

Comment: Stefan, I think it is not good to delete the old post, because sometimes people give comments or even answer your question (but by some reason you can't accept this answer), and this information is often useful for you and for those who want to answer. Besides this, it happens sometimes that your question is too simple for MO, and people send you back to Math.SE.

Comment: If you already received useful information you should use it to create a new version of your question, rather than to just copy paste the old one. I do not understand the point of   "Besides this, it happens sometimes that your question is too simple for MO, and people send you back to Math.SE." If you mean this speaks against deletion in itself, I do not see it, as you just can undelete at any time. (I am not sure deletion is always the best, but the argument is unconvincing.)

Comment: quid, sometimes it happens that somebody writes in comments (or in answer) something absolutely incomprehensible for non-specialists (like in the answer that I finally accepted here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177741/is-antipode-unique-for-bialgebras-in-arbitrary-monoidal-categories ). If you are not a specialist (and this is the usual situation), it is difficult to understand what is actually useful in people's comments. I would say, deleting what people write, is not good. And I did not know that it is possible to undelete question.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: You cannot (and should not) delete answered questions. What I meant is that you can delete a question which just got forgotten on Math.SE, and then post it here.

Comment: Stefan, and the questions with comments, can they be deleted?

Comment: They can. -- If there are useful comments, you should consider them when preparing the MO version of your question, and give appropriate credit to the authors of the comments.

Comment: I see. You know, I still don't like the idea of deleting somebody's comments, unless it becomes evident for the OP himself that the question is stupid.

Comment: Of course, if you do not receive answer at Math.SE, you can also try a [bounty](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/bounty/info) before posting it on another site. And, of course, if you post the question to another site, you should definitely link both copies/versions to each other.